# Why does Belarus not seem to have ratified any protocol from European Convention on Human Rights?

Tags: human-rights, echr, belarus

[Territorial scope of European Convention on Human Rights Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Territorial_scope_of_European_Convention_on_Human_Rights) does not include Belarus.

Human rights issues are confirmed by multiple articles such as [this one](https://www.amnesty.org/en/countries/europe-and-central-asia/belarus/report-belarus/):

> The government continued to refuse to accept the mandate of the UN
>   Special Rapporteur on human rights in Belarus. Several individuals
>   seeking international protection were returned to countries where they
>   were at risk of torture and other ill-treatment. Heavy legislative
>   restrictions on media, NGOs, political parties and public assemblies
>   remained in place. One person was executed and four were sentenced to
>   death.

Coming back to European Convention on Human Rights country list, I see that many, if not almost all Post-Soviet states (e.g. Armenia, Azerbaijan, Estonia, Georgia, Russia) have ratified several or all the protocols (some exceptions may occur) from the Convention.

So, being a Post-Soviet state does not seem to be an important factor when ratifying ECHR protocols.

**Question:** Why does Belarus not seem to have ratified any protocol from European Convention on Human Rights?

Comment: Why would you ratify a treaty if you don’t intend to follow it?

Comment: @chirlu - good point, but it is strange anyway. I do not know for sure, but I think that all other European countries (including Russia) have at least partially ratified ECHR. Some of these countries have had human-rights related issues and yet have signed at least one protocol from ECHR.

Comment: This is really not a real question.  Can someone expect a dictator to allow its citizens to enjoy human rights? Also:  https://www.independent.co.uk/news/world/europe/russia-echr-human-rights-european-convention-putin-kremlin-eu-a8234086.html

Comment: @yahoo.com your comment seems like an attempt at an answer.

Comment: Worth noting that (unlike the other countries listed), Belarus is not a member of the Council of Europe. Which (non-membership, and non-ratification of the ECHR) is cause, and which is effect, I do not know.